# How to stop centered list from ofsetting to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css

I realise this question has been asked a few times before, but I have a list that is being displayed as an inline block for use as a nav bar. I want the nav bare to be centered on the webpage, and if possible, to handle being scaled down a bit.

```
<ul class="nav_bar">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
```

This is the list and this is the CSS I'm using

```
.nav_bar li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image:url(../hubheading.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav_bar {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The problem is that the list is offset to the right slightly, I've tried several things including putting a div around the list, but that seems to make all the CSS not work completely... For me at least, that's why I'm asking for help. I have no issues with using Jquery to help if that's going to actually work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ul` has default left-padding, pushing its contents over a bit.

```
.nav_bar{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
```

should do the trick.  Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/HuJzx

Comment: This is one of those "I can't believe I did that" moments... Thanks a lot mate, I've been racking my brain for over 12 hours

Answer (score 0):

I see in your question that you are applying `margin:0px;` property to all elements in your CSS therefore you can try this:

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:99%;  // for .nav_bar li

margin:0 auto;padding:0;width:auto;height:auto       // for .nav_bar

text-align: center;          // for the container of .nav_bar
```